# Вывод видео MediaPlayer Android

Tags: android, java, android-mediaplayer

Здравствуйте, проблема в следующем: не могу вывести видео (программа зависает):

```
    try {
         final String DSTREAM = "http://***.3gp";
         mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
         mediaplayer.setDataSource(DSTREAM);
         mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         mediaplayer.setDisplay(surfaceview.getHolder());
         mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
         mediaplayer.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: тут масса вопросов...    
на пример, пытаетесь воспроизвести 3gp как STREAM_MUSIC    
воспроизведение, собственно, просто не начинаете (mediaplayer.start())    
И стактрейс, если таковой имеется нужен тоже...

Comment: Воспроизведение, собственно, просто не начинаете (mediaplayer.start()).

Извиняюсь показал отрывок кода. Проблема была в SurfaceHolder не мог получить в onCreate, получил в onResume.

Comment: оформите ваш комментарий, как ответ, и закройте вопрос, если он решен